# How was Frieza able to anticipate Yardrat's Instant transmission in Dragon ball Super?

Tags: plot-explanation, dragon-ball-super

In episode 108, Frieza was easily able to anticipate Yardrat's Instant transmission while Gohan couldn't. Frieza almost beat Yardrat to death. How was Frieza able to move faster than Instant transmission? Instant transmission is said to travel at a speed almost equal to light. Does Frieza have the ability to travel faster than light? Or is it just a small distance thing wherein he anticipates where Yardart might pop up and then appear over there.

Answer (score 1):

Frieza watched the fight between Gohan and Yardrat, so could have predict the pattern of fighting of Yardrat.

Frieza is more experienced than Gohan and this is not the first time Frieza had an opponent use instant transmission in a fight. And Frieza is good with fighting with his tail, which not everyone will notice at first.